# Javascript add onclick unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, html

My Script :

```
function $(attr){
    if(attr.charAt(0) == "#"){
        return document.getElementById(attr.substr(1));
    }else{
        if(attr.charAt(0) == "."){
            return document.getElementsByClassName(attr.substr(1));
        }else{
            return document.getElementsByTagName(attr);
        }
    }
}

Object.prototype.onclick = function(script){
    this.onclick = script;
}

$("#hi").onclick(function(){alert("hi");});
```

In html it's just a label with id `hi`.

When I click the button, nothing happened. 
What should I do?

Comment: If you don't need support for very old browsers I'd just use `querySelectorAll`, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll. `getElementsByClassName` isn't very well supported either in old IE FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Extending `Object` is bad practice, I wouldn't recommend it. Also in modern browsers what you want to do is fairly easy, you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), and add events with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
// An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
var $ = (function() {
  // Constructor
  function $(selector) {
    // querySelectorAll returns a pseudo-array
    this.el = toArray(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  }
  // Get elements as array or an element by index
  $.prototype.get = function(i) {
    return i == null ? this.el : this.el[i];
  };
  // Public method to add any event
  $.prototype.on = function(event, f) {
    this.el.forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener(event, f);
    });
    // chain
    return this;
  };
  // shortcut for click event
  $.prototype.click = function(f) {
    return this.on('click', f);
  };
  // Coverts pseudo-arrays to real arrays
  function toArray(x) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
  }
  // Wrapper to create instances
  // without using the "new" keyword
  return function(x) {
    return new $(x);
  }
}());

$('#hi').click(function(){alert('hi')});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/HtKk8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#hi").onclick=function(){alert("hi");}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(...).onclick is not a function.` solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could just leave it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function $(attr){
    if(attr.charAt(0) == "#"){
        return document.getElementById(attr.substr(1));
    }else{
        if(attr.charAt(0) == "."){
            return document.getElementsByClassName(attr.substr(1));
        }else{
            return document.getElementsByTagName(attr);
        }
    }
}

$("#hi").onclick = function(){alert("hi");};
</script>
```

here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/29NYx/

Answer (score 0):

My friend check the ID by using Inspect Element after your page is loaded in a browser.

I am guessing that you are using ASP.NET with a MasterPage and your #hi element is inside a contentPlaceHolder. If my guess is right then your element #hi must have change into something like ContentPlaceHolder1_hi. So according to this please change your script.

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hi').click(function(){alert('hi')});
```

I hope this helps.